# Как копировать данные между Таблицами

Tags: google-apps-script, импорт, google-spreadsheet, google-drive

Есть скрипт, который импортирует данные с одной гугл-таблицы в другую.

Проблема в том, что оба документа должны быть идентичны по количеству строк. Так как первый документ динамический, то второй всего приходится поправлять руками до нужного числа строк (как в первом документе).

Скажите, как избавиться от этой зависимости? Чтобы импортировать диапазон, вне зависимости от того, сколько строк во документе, который получает эти данные. И как импортировать не только в ячейку A1, а, например, в ячейку B2? C3? и так далее...
[Пример данных](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cnOMB8kY4ljJzLLM7HPlsyjopCKuGnae?usp=sharing)

```
function onOpen2(e) {
  // исходный документ
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Ключ');
  // исходный лист
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Лист');
  // Получить диапазон данных
  var SRange = ss.getRange('A:D');
  // Скопировать в ячейку. В данном случае (A1)
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  // получить значения данных в диапазоне
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  // Целевая таблица. Куда выгружаем
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Ключ');
  // Целевой лист. Куда импортируем
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('лист');
  // Очищение диапазона перед копированием.
  ts.getRange('A1:D').clearContent();
  // Скопировать в ячейку. В данном случае (A1)
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
}
```

Comment: Это невозможно понять. Что за строки? Что за динамика? Зачем все это? Может быть начнете с примера? В чем суть вашего заголовка для темы?

Comment: Добавил ссылки на пример. Это необходимо для того, чтобы можно было импортировать данные с одного документа, в другой. Формула importrange - не справляется, т.к. у нее появились ограничения в 25 тысяч строк (у меня массив в 100к + 10+ столбцов), поэтому данный массив я могу импортировать лишь с помощью гугл скрипта. Но проблема в том, что два файла должны быть одинакового размера, если в исходном файле 100 тысяч строк, то и во втором должно быть 100 тысяч строк. Как убрать эту зависимость при импорте данных ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код из топика немного странный. При обилии комментариев не понятно, почему возникла проблема копирования. Вот рабочий пример

```
/**
 * Copy values between two sheets
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet} from Source sheet
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet} to Destination sheet
 * @returns {undefined}
 */

function copyValuesBetweenTwoSheets_(from, to) {
  var values = from.getRange('A2:D').getValues();

  to.clearContents();
  to.getRange(3, 3, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

В примере показано, что `C3` - ячейка, с которой начинается вставка, хотя данные берутся из ячейки `A2` и далее.

Рабочий пример [тут](https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/spreadsheet_copy_values_between_two_sheets/spreadsheet_copy_values_between_two_sheets.js).

Comment: Спасибо Вам, добрый человек :)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Вы можете отметить ответ как решение.